# Php mysql time stamp - 2 hours

Tags: php, time

I have this working for the current time in PHP:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

I cant figure out how to append this to have the current time -2 hours in this same format.
Can anyone help me out quick?
Thank you!

Comment: Googling `Php mysql time stamp - 2 hours`, or `php subtract timestap` will give you all you need. Please always check that out first.

Comment: Downvotes? WHY. Its a valid question.

Comment: It's an incredibly lazy question that could have been answered with 10 seconds of googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
    $minus_two_hrs = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-2 hours"));
```

The `strtotime()` function returns a timestamp, which you can then pass to `date()` to get the appropriately formatted date.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
$time = time();
$prevtime = strtotime("-2 hours"); // time -2 hours
$date = data("Y-m-d H:i:s", $prevtime); // time -2 hours
```

Hope it helps ;)

Link:
[PHP.net strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime)

Comment: Why have you created variable `$time` ?

Comment: `$time` is the current time, it was just for demonstration I think...

Answer (score 0):

You can also manipulate the unix timestamp manually; because the timestamps are in seconds:

e.g.

```
// Get current time in seconds
$time_now = time();

// Take 2 hours (in seconds) away from current timestamp
$two_hours_ago = $time_now - (60 * 2);

// Display calculated value
echo "Two hours ago: " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $two_hours_ago);
```

The above can be done as a one-liner also:

e.g.

```
echo echo "Two hours ago: " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - (60 * 2));
```

Comment: that gives me 1387468823 
$time_now = time();
$two_hours_ago = $time_now - (60 * 2);
echo $two_hours_ago;

Comment: Yes, the manual processing returns the unix timestamp back in seconds. If you want to display it in a nice format way, you use `date()` function on it. Let me update my post.